How to reuse RestSharp RestClient instance for many requests that do not have same base URI?
RestSharp Documentation
I can use the HttpClient instance created without any base URI, and add all details in HttpRequestMessage to reuse the HttpClient instance.
class Example
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client;

    static Example()
    {
        client = new(new SocketsHttpHandler
        {
            PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)
        });
    }

    private void MakeHttpRequest() {
        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = "www.example.com/uri"
        };
        var response = client.GetAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
        //rest  of the code
    }
}

How can I do that in RestSharp 's RestClient. How to send the full request URI in the RestRequest Object itself?
RestRequest constructor seems to be only looking for relative URI
/// <summary>
/// Constructor for a rest request to a relative resource URL and optional method
/// </summary>
/// <param name="resource">Resource to use</param>
/// <param name="method">Method to use (defaults to Method.Get></param>
public RestRequest(string? resource, Method method = Method.Get) : this() {
    Resource = resource ?? "";
    Method   = method;
    //rest of the code
}


Does this answer your question? Setting dynamic baseUrl for Get Request RestClient

Or maybe this? BaseHost URL setting in RestSharp

None of the above work for my question. I want to reuse same RestClient

You can do that by passing an HttpClient to the RestClient constructor.
Please make sure that you don't set the BaseUrl otherwise it won't work.
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var client = new RestClient(httpClient);

var request1 = new RestRequest("https://httpbin.org/status/200");
var response1 = client.Execute(request1);
Console.WriteLine(response1.StatusCode); //OK

var request2 = new RestRequest("https://postman-echo.com/status/201");
var response2 = client.Execute(request2);
Console.WriteLine(response2.StatusCode); //Created

Dotnet fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cg6wlh

RestSharp supports empty base URL and absolute path for the request resource.
Here's one test from RestSharp codebase:
[Fact]
public void GET_with_empty_base_and_resource_containing_tokens() {
    var request = new RestRequest("http://example.com/resource/{foo}");
    request.AddUrlSegment("foo", "bar");

    using var client = new RestClient();

    var expected = new Uri("http://example.com/resource/bar");
    var output   = client.BuildUri(request);

    Assert.Equal(expected, output);
}

